# SQLite CE exception - Database is locked

Tags: .net, sqlite, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have a trouble with the following code. The program seems to stuck sometimes (apparently no pattern...often in the second query since the form containing this code run but not always) for 5-20 seconds in the row

Dim rdr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

If the code doesn't stuck in second query since form started, it won't never stuck. If I close and reopen the form I have the same 50-60% chance to have same error mostly on 2nd query.

Then it always restart from this point sometimes with no error...just big delay of 5-20 seconds and sometimes with error "The database file is locked, database is locked" at line

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
(2° time..not inside if block)

This error will forbid the user to save its change and sometimes corrupt the data record and, of course, introduces a huge delay that I can't accept :(

Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong?

I'm developing with visual studio 2008 for a windows CE 6.0 device with 3.5 framework and

ADO.NET 2.0/3.5 SQLite Data Provider
Version 1.0.66.0 April 18, 2010
Using SQLite 3.6.23.1
http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Thank you

```
'Update current program on database
Public Sub AggiornaUserOnDatabase(ByVal name As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal permission As String)
    'No spaces
    name = Trim(name)
    'Database var
    Dim ConString As String = "Data Source = " + DatabaseAccountPath + ";"
    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection
    Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand
    'Read from database
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = ConString
        con.Open()
        'Check if row is existing
        cmd = con.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + DBACCNAME + " FROM " + DatabaseAccountTableName + " WHERE " + DBACCNAME + " = '" + name + "'"
        Dim rdr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        'If empty...create the record
        If Not rdr.Read Then
            cmd = con.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + DatabaseAccountTableName + " (" + DBACCNAME + ") VALUES ('" + name + "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        rdr.close()
        'Update the values
        cmd = con.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " + DatabaseAccountTableName + " SET " _
                        + DBACCPASSWORD + " = '" + password + "', " _
                        + DBACCPERMISSION + " = '" + permission + "' " _
                        + "WHERE " + DBACCNAME + " = '" + name + "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        AggiungiRigaSuFile(ErroriPath, "Editing users account database: " + ex.Message, Configurazione.DiagnosticaOff, True)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Terrible problem statement. "Seems to stuck".  "if not in second query seems to never stuck ?!"   What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry for poor english...I meant:
1st Query -> OK
2nd Query -> problem 60-70% of the times
If I have no problem with 2nd query since form with this code  started I will not have any problem in future queries...I need to close form and re-open it and try for 2nd query since opening again...
Quite confusing to figure and also to explain..hope you got point

Comment: Better explanation but update the question.  Don't expect people to read comments for problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the cmd when it has an open reader.  You need to close the reader before you use the cmd again.  And don't even use a reader.  Do a select count(*) to to see if the record exists.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + ...
int rowRet = (Int32)sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar();

if (rowCount == 0)
{
    // do NOT create the command gain just use it
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + DatabaseAccountTableName ...
    // insert all the values here so the update is not required
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else if (rowCount == 1)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " + DatabaseAccountTableName + " SET " _
                    + DBACCPASSWORD + " = '" + password + "', " _
                    + DBACCPERMISSION + " = '" + permission + "' " _
                    + "WHERE " + DBACCNAME + " = '" + name + "'"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else 
{
     // throw an error expected 0 or 1
}
```

Comment: What you mean? Could you explain in code changes?
Should I do "rdr.close" before next update command?

Comment: Show your rdr.close().  Better yet don't use rdr at all.  select count(*) and insert if the count = 0.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how use select count(*) in this code, could you show it? I added rdr.close in top code...I'm sgoogling but can't find how to use count as you said

Comment: Dude, you still have an open reader on the insert command!  Basically you an open read on a table you are trying to write to and you are wondering why you are getting lock.

Comment: Blam, thanks for clarification. This will explain why problem would stuck in the ExecuteNonQuery inside IF...but that block is always skipped in my problem because record already exist...I have problem with next ExecuteNonQuery Statement.
Thanks anyway cause I will fix my code for other istances when code will run inside that if.